# Bash variable gets butchered when being inserted into cURL command

Tags: bash, shell, curl

**The first part of the script looks like:**

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d 'username=username&password=password "https://get_token" >> token.txt
token=$(<'token.txt'$'\r')
echo "$token"
```

**The output from echo $token looks fine(417 characters):**

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk9pS3FDeHhcLzk1dz09IiwibmJmIjoxNDgzOTg5NjgwLCJpc3MiOiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw
```

**Let's see what happens when I try to insert the token into the next part of the script.**

```
echo curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: AR-JWT "$token"" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ 
  "values":{
      
    "First_Name": "John",
    "Last_Name": "Doe",
  }
}  ' "https://randomurl.com"
```

**Here is the output:**

```
curl -k -X POST -H Content-Type: application/json -H Authorization: AR-JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk9pS3FDeHhcLzk1dz0 -H Cache-Control: no-cache -d { OiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw
  "values":{
      
    "First_Name": "John",
    "Last_Name": "Doe",
  }
}   https://randomurl.com
```

**2 Things happen when the token is passed in**

- "9IiwibmJmIjoxNDgzOTg5NjgwLCJpc3Mi" within the token gets deleted
- The 2nd half of the token(After the deleted part) gets inserted into the body

**What I've tried:**

- Using a different token
- Use token without passing it into a file first
- Moving the Authorization header before the URL

All of these results in the same behavior.

I'm using cygwin64 on Windows 7
When the second cURL command is typed with full token in the correct space into cygwin, it works no problem

Output when set-x is added to the script:

```
$ ./variable_testing.sh
+ ./variable_testing.sh
+ token=$'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk9pS3FDeHhcLzk1dz09IiwibmJmIjoxNDgzOTg5NjgwLCJpc3MiOiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw\r'
+ echo $'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk9pS3FDeHhcLzk1dz09IiwibmJmIjoxNDgzOTg5NjgwLCJpc3MiOiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw\r\r'
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk9pS3FDeHhcLzk1dz09IiwibmJmIjoxNDgzOTg5NjgwLCJpc3MiOiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw
+ echo curl -k -X POST -H '"Content-Type:' 'application/json"' -H '"Authorization:' AR-JWT 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk"' -H '"Cache-Control:' 'no-cache"' -d '{ LCJpc3MiOiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw
  "values":{
      
    "First_Name": "John",
    "Last_Name": "Doe",
  }
}  ' $'https://randomurl.com\r'
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: AR-JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk9pS3FDeHhcLzk1" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d { OiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw
  "values":{
      
    "First_Name": "John",
    "Last_Name": "Doe",
  }
}   https://randomurl.com
```

Full, simplified script that that displays output above

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x logs
token="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyTVd0bGo4Y1VPYW8xNmdZTlV4QWlFS3RLcTc1b2JsSEN0c3hKWnlxeExCTkRKb1wvKzNSK1l5XC9YUFhoWExLaytJRVdKSE5CTE9MZmxPNksxemFjYXVlM0t1NnFIQjNRXC9QeUxzUTdVSmVOYk9pS3FDeHhcLzk1dz09IiwibmJmIjoxNDgzOTg5NjgwLCJpc3MiOiJwaHgtcmVtc3QtMDAzIiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjE0MzA0OCwiZXhwIjoxNDgzOTkzNDAwLCJpYXQiOjE0ODM5ODk4MDAsImp0aSI6IklER0FBNVYwR1pNU0pBTzk5QlVXTzhOMDY5VlRGTiJ9.H3vD-WfZBFXOII4k-cy7Ey2QM9YXytp31m9-Huj9vKw"
echo "$token"
echo curl -k -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"Authorization: AR-JWT $token\" -H \"Cache-Control: no-cache\" -d '{ 
  "values":{
      
    "First_Name": "John",
    "Last_Name": "Doe",
  }
}  ' "https://randomurl.com"
```

Comment: The quoting in `-H "Authorization: AR-JWT "$token""`... I mean, frankly, what do you *intend* it to mean? Do you want the internal quotes to be literal, vs syntactic?

Comment: BTW, use `printf '%q\n' "$token"`, or `declare -p token`, not `echo "$token"`, to display your value in an unambiguous form.

Comment: I struggle to find the final single quote in the first code sample.

Comment: In the first part of the script you've also forgotten a closing single-quote after the `-d` parameter

Comment: In general -- **don't ever** use `echo` to debug what the shell is actually doing. You can't tell the difference between `echo touch "hello world.txt"` and `echo touch hello world.txt`, and those two commands are utterly unlike each other.

Comment: Moreover, `echo touch \"hello world.txt\"` *looks* correct, whereas in fact it's wildly wrong/broken since it has only syntactic and not literal quotes. `echo` is simply the Wrong Tool for debugging.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the first set of double quotes should be literal, forgot to escape them. The quotes for $token aren't exactly need, I just put them in to see if they would hold the token together.

Comment: Could you update your question to show `set -x` logs, so we can see what the shell is *actually* passing to `curl`?

Comment: (and... wait... *which* quotes should be literal? It doesn't look to me like AR-JWT expects any literal quotes).

Comment: (...btw, appending to your token store, vs truncating and creating, is... surprising to me that it would be desired/intended behavior).

Comment: Also, what's with `token=$(<'token.txt'$'\r')`? Do you really have a CR at the end of your filename? I would tend to expect that to be evidence of a bug, as opposed to something you'd want to keep. (If your script is in CRLF format but cygwin is reading it expecting UNIX lines... well, convert it to a UNIX text-file format, with lines properly terminated with LF only!)

Comment: Hi Charles, I've changed token file to unix, and added set-x to the script before running it again.

Comment: Since a CR, when printed, moves the cursor location, having them printed as literals means that you can't trust what you're reading on your terminal to be correct, vs having content overwritten where the cursor was moved around.

Comment: Charles, I've added the entire script in the question, please let me know what needs to be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132733/discussion-between-songjaegu-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: Your token currently has literal CRs in it -- the apparent butchering is caused by those CRs being printed in your `echo` output, moving the cursor back to the beginning of the line so parts of your token get overwritten with later content. To eliminate them, you can either convert the file into UNIX text format (and ensure that there aren't CRs in any of the commands generating that file), or you can use:

```
token=$(<token.txt)    # read token.txt into "token" variable
token=${token//$'\r'/} # strip CRs from token variable
```

If you want to pass the Authorization header to `curl` as a single word, don't end and reinitialize your quotes; keep that single argument inside one set of syntactic quotes.

```
-H "Authorization: AR-JWT $token"
```

Finally, make sure your script itself is in UNIX format -- that your editor isn't saving it with DOS newlines.

Comment: I have spent 2 hours to find out why I had this problem. Stripping the CRs from the token variable did it. Thanks!!